# My nav bar only works on the index page. I can't navigate back to any other page if i am not on index page

Tags: html, navigation, navbar, nav

I am trying to make a website to wish a friend on his birthday. And My nav bar only works on the index page. I can't navigate back to any other page if i am not on index page.

I've tried almost everything i know to fix it but i couldn't. Would someone please guide me to fix it. Thanks in advance.

This is just the code of nav bar. Rest of the code is working totally fine that's why i didn't add it. But I can surely share the code if you think that rest of the is messing with that one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Happy Birthday Manhoos</title>
<meta name="description" content="Some SVG shape animations for fun letter effects" />
<meta name="keywords" content="svg, animation, letter, word, shapes, javascript, animejs" />
<meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
<script>document.documentElement.className = "js"; var supportsCssVars = function () { var e,
t = document.createElement("style"); return t.innerHTML = "root: { --tmp-var: bold; }", 
document.head.appendChild(t), e = !!(window.CSS && window.CSS.supports && 
window.CSS.supports("font-weight", "var(--tmp-var)")), t.parentNode.removeChild(t), e }; 
supportsCssVars() || alert("Please view this demo in a modern browser that supports CSS 
Variables.");</script>
</head>

<body class="demo-1">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blessed Friends</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="../../index.html">Ahmmm Ahmmm</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../Bootstrap 
                    Website/Wish/Wish/index.html">Surprise</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="../Bootstrap 
                    Website/Wish/Wish/index.html">Prayers</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="../Bootstrap 
                    Website/Wish/Wish/index.html">Gift</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" 
                        role="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Memories
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">First Time Ever Moments</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Funniest</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Happiest</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dramatic</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Excited</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blessed</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SAD</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown end</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Type Here" aria- 
                label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: But everything is linked to index.html?

Comment: Have you included the navbar code on all the other `.html` pages?

Comment: Yes, I've linked it to the index.html.